# Creating a simple app, can't get clear button to work

Tags: java, android

So, I'm trying to follow along this website's tutorial.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent

I did the first part where I got the text box and a send button.  I can enter text in the text box and click send.  But the text box's text stays there.  It doesn't disappear.  So, the next part of the tutorial is how to get the text to disappear.  I'm trying to follow along, but I can't get it to work.

Here's my code.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_clear"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


strings.xml

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">The Most Useless App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
</resources>


MainActivity.xml

package com.example.myfirstapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);



    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.myfirstapp">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
                <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value=".MainActivity" />
            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

            // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(message);



        }


    }
```

Errors I get

> Cannot resolve symbol textView
>
> Cannot resolve symbol activity_display_message
>
> Cannot resolve symbol EXTRA_MESSAGE
>
> The activity com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity is not registered in
>   the manifest.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is a setting problem,  the first thing you should do is 
to do a clean build, you can select above android studio the option `buld` and then `clean build`. If does not work please post the output of your `build.gradle` [file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build)

There is also the possibility that you are just starting with android, and you do not know that have to import sometimes the needed libraries

Point your mouse to `MainActivity` and press alt+enter if you are in windows, and select add `Activity` to `AndroidManifest`, then do a clean build.

I suggest you to use the wizard building a new project, you go to Android studio and select file new project and follow the project, so MainActivity will be automatically added to your manifest